# Proof of $ \text{Poisson}(\lambda p) $-arrivals.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, queueing-theory

We have a queue where people pass out of it with $ \text{Poisson}(\lambda) $ and they come in with probability $ p $.

I understand that the arrivals follow $ \text{Poisson}(\lambda p) $, but how can I prove it?

Comment: I dont understand your question the way its worded. It sounds like you want us to prove a given?

Comment: What do you mean "come in with probability $p$"? Also, I don't understand how arrivals follow Poisson distribution with smaller mean than departures unless something funny is happening in the queue.

Comment: @Inquest +1 for `something funny`.

Comment: I mean that people decide if they are coming in with probability p,otherwise they pass outside of it and they are not been counted as arrivals.Only for those who come in the mean of arrivals and departures is going to be the same,λp.

Answer (score 1):

Let X be the number of arrivals.
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&P(X=r)=\sum\limits_{k=r}^{\infty}\dfrac{\lambda ^k}{k!}\exp{(-\lambda)}C_k^rp^r(1-p)^{k-r}\\
&&=\sum\limits_{k=r}^{\infty}\exp{(-\lambda)}\dfrac{\lambda ^k k!}{r!(k-r)!k!}p^r(1-p)^{k-r}\\
&&=\dfrac{\lambda^r p^r}{r!}\sum\limits_{k=r}^{\infty}\exp{(-\lambda)}\dfrac{\lambda ^{k-r} }{(k-r)!}(1-p)^{k-r}\\
&&=\dfrac{\lambda^r p^r}{r!}\exp{(-\lambda)}\exp{(\lambda(1-p))}=\dfrac{(\lambda p)^r}{r!}e^{-\lambda p}
\end{eqnarray*}
So $X\sim P(\lambda p)$

Comment: The first step is where the thing lies and you do not even explain it? On a question already fully answered 5 years ago? Sorry but there must be more useful investments of your time on this site...

Comment: I am sorry. I just see the related problem on the right and give a sample answer.

Comment: Is "sample answer" a codeword for "unmotivated and ultimately not useful to the OP, answer"?

Comment: I do agree with @Did, for anyone wondering where it comes from, here is a question where something similar has been derived: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777427/splitting-poisson-process-formal-proof

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool proof I thought about.

I am going to split the original process into two parts, one that can arise with probability p and the other with probability 1-p. Here in your example, the original process is passing out, with proba p going in, proba 1-p not going in.

Now what we want to prove is how the splitted process is still a poisson process, and this will give us the proof that your process is indeed poisson with parameter $\lambda p$.

Also, since it is the case that interested me, I prove it for poisson proceses, not poisson random variables (replace $\lambda$ by $\lambda t $.

> We have the poisson process
>
> $$X(t) = X_1(t) + X_2(t) $$
>
> First we calculate the joint probability
>
> $$P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t)
> > = m \mid X(t) = n]P[X(t) = n]$$
>
> Note that
>
> $$P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m \mid X(t) = n] = 0 \:\:\: \text{when}\:\: n
> > \neq k+m$$
>
> Now
>
> $$P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m] = P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m \mid X(t) =
> > k+m]P[X(t) = k+m]$$
>
> $$= P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m \mid X(t) = k+m]e^{-\lambda
> > t}\frac{(\lambda t)^{k+m}}{(k+m)!}$$
>
> Now, given that $k+m$ events occurred, since each event has
>   probability $p$ of being a type $1$ event and probability $1-p$ of
>   being a type $2$ event, it follows that
>
> $$P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m \mid X(t) = k+m] = \binom{k+m}{k}
> > p^k(1-p)^m$$
>
> Thus,
>
> $$P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m] = \binom{k+m}{k} p^k(1-p)^m e^{-\lambda
> > t}\frac{(\lambda t)^{k+m}}{(k+m)!}$$
>
> $$= \frac{(k+m)!}{k!m!} p^k(1-p)^m e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda
> > t)^{k+m}}{(k+m)!}$$
>
> $$= e^{-\lambda p t} \frac{(\lambda p t)^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda(1-p) t}
> > \frac{[\lambda (1 - p)t]^m}{m!} \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(1)$$
>
> Then
>
> $$P(X_1 = k) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m]$$
>
> $$=e^{-\lambda p t} \frac{(\lambda p t)^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda(1-p) t}
> > \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{[\lambda (1 - p)t]^m}{m!}$$
>
> $$= e^{-\lambda p t} \frac{(\lambda p t)^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda(1-p) t}
> > e^{\lambda(1-p) t}$$
>
> $$=e^{-\lambda p t} \frac{(\lambda p t)^k}{k!} \:\:\:\:\:\: (2)$$
>
> which indicates that $X_1(t)$ is a poisson process with rate $\lambda
> > p$.
>
> Similarly, we can obtain
>
> $$P(X_2(t) = m) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m]$$
>
> $$= e^{-\lambda(1-p) t} \frac{[\lambda (1 - p)t]^m}{m!} \:\:\:\:\:\:
> > (3)$$
>
> and so $X_2(t)$ is a poisson process with rate $\lambda (1-p)$.
>
> Finally, from equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$
>
> $$P[X_1(t) = k, X_2(t) = m] = P[X_1(t) = k]P[X_2(t) = m]$$
>
> Hence, $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$ are independent.

Then you have the answer to your problem ! I am not sure that there is a simplier way to prove it, other than intuition.

The original part of the proof comes from here : [Splitting Poisson process formal proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777427/splitting-poisson-process-formal-proof) and the reward of the work should be attributed to JKnecht. I wanted to use his proof for another interesting similar case, which is yours, because in the end, it is the same problem.

Comment: What's the deal ? you can't just put a -1 and leave without comments. I am pretty happy with my proof, at least it convinces me.